# How can I get the 'ls' output to a variable in grub2?

Tags: command-line, grub2, grub

I install Ubuntu into a SSD drive and when I insert the SSD into different computer I have to change manually the disk number. I would like to get the home directory of all the disks until I found the one in the SSD.

In order to do that I need to know how to save the output of commands into variables (specially 'ls') Is that even possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to capture the output of `ls`, you need to look up the `search` command in `grub`.

> Search devices by file ('-f', '--file'), filesystem label ('-l', '--label'), or filesystem UUID ('-u', '--fs-uuid').

Basically it allows you to search for your SSD either by some file present on the SSD or by filesystem label or UUID.